# Not able to see BizTalk templates for HL7 in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, sql-server-2012, biztalk, biztalk-2013r2, btahl7

I have installed `Visual Studio 2013`, `BizTalk 2013R2`, `BizTalk accelerator for HL7` and `SQL Server 2012` in my local machine.

But in Visual Studio, Project templates for BizTalk is missing. Only Empty BizTalk Server Project is displaying in Templates section under Installed.

I am not getting what I have done wrong. I have gone through every steps and every websites which can help me out from this problem but I am not able to see.

Can anyone tell me the solution for this problem. I am stuck because I am not getting "**BTAHL7V21Common**", "**BTAHL7V22Common**" etc. templates.

Any help will be appreciated.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You have to have SQL Server 2012 Data Tools & SDK installed.

Refer to this post:

[HL7: I am missing my project templates in Visual Studio 2012](http://www.robfox.nl/2014/03/07/hl7-i-am-missing-my-project-templates-in-visual-studio-2012/)